# Is it possible to get 3rd party specials data through the Foursquare venues/search endpoint?

Tags: api, foursquare

I've noticed that when using the Foursquare API venues/search endpoint, the venues are not being returned with all the specials I find on the website using explore.  These venues are returned with Foursquare specials but not 3rd party specials. I've also explored the specials/search and venues details endpoints with no luck.

The example below is the venues/search api call that will return a single venue called "Fainting Goat Pub".  Currently this venue has a Scoutmob special that is visible on the Foursquare website but not in the API results.

So, is it possible to use the venues/search endpoint to get venue information along with 3rd party deals like those provided by Scoutmob?  If not, how do we go about getting that information?

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXX...XXXXXX&ll=39.729966,-104.987022&intent=checkin&limit=50&radius=50&v=20120101&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06376d81259

Answer (score 1):

Specials from daily deal providers are currently not exposed via the API.